# Odd interaction of secnumdepth and section-based counters

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

In the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{exnum}[subsection]
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter}
  \section*{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection A}
      \setcounter{exnum}{1}
      Exnum is \theexnum.
    \subsection{Subsection B}
      Exnum is \theexnum.
\end{document}
```

I get the output I expected; namely, the line printed in Subsection A is `Exnum is 1` and in Subsection B is `Exnum is 0`. However, in the actual code, I didn't want subsection numbers printed, so I changed both occurrences of `\subsection` to `\subsection*`. The output then consisted of `Exnum is 1` in both subsections. As a workaround, starting from the code above, I instead added the line `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` at the top, just after the documentclass, to prevent printing the subsection numbers, but left the `\subsection`s unstarred. Again the output was `Exnum is 1` in both subsections.

What is going on here? Are these two manifestations of the same failure, or are they different problems? And, what don't I understand about what secnumdepth does? I thought it simply prevented printing of section numbers, but clearly it does much more than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if the subsection counter is not incremented (and that will be the case if you use `\subsection*` or `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`) then your counter won't be reset.

Using the `titlesec` package you can redefine your subsections to suppress the numbering from the document, but to still internally increase the counter, so your new counter will still be reset when a new subsection is created:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{exnum}[subsection]

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter}
  \section*{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection A}
      \setcounter{exnum}{1}
      Exnum is \theexnum.
    \subsection{Subsection B}
      Exnum is \theexnum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. The documentation for secnumdepth (and subsection*) don't mention actually not incrementing the counter - they just say the counter is not printed. Anyway, this worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

let the  `\subsection` itself reset the counter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\let\SubSection\subsection
\def\subsection{\setcounter{exnum}{0}\SubSection}
\newcounter{exnum}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter}
  \section*{Section 1}
    \subsection*{Subsection A}
      \setcounter{exnum}{1}
      Exnum is \theexnum.
    \subsection*{Subsection B}
      Exnum is \theexnum.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the way numbers are printed:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \csname @seccntformat#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\def\@seccntformatsubsection#1#2{}
\makeatother
```

The usual definition is

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
```

and we simply add a new command before this; since we are defining only `\@seccntformatsubsection`, when LaTeX will try `\@seccntformatsection` it will consider it as `\relax`; when it wants to typeset a subsection, it will be presented (after the first expansion) with

```
\@seccntformatsubsection\thesubsection\quad
```

and `\@seccntformatsubsectio` will gobble the two tokens. Setting `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` will "number" the subsections, but `\subsection{A title}` will eventually print *without* the number.